# Accept decimal numbers (currency) with html5 and jquery validate

Tags: html, jquery-validate

My input is defined like this:

```
<input type="number" required="required" step="0.01" />
```

The only rule i have defined for that input in jquery validate is:

```
  itemprice: {
        required: true
            },
```

Yet when I try to enter "5.50" i get back

```
Please enter a multiple of 0.01.
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery Validate plugin automatically disables the browser's HTML5 validation while also using the inline HTML5 attributes to set the rules.  So your inline `step` attribute is automatically declaring the plugin's `step` method.

Since you intend on disabling HTML5 validation by using the jQuery Validate plugin, you can remove the HTML5 attributes.  Otherwise, there is no mechanism for telling this plugin to ignore HTML5 attributes when applying rules.